# How to make a generic database record to object conversion function?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I am using the following function to retrieve records from a database and convert the records to a collection of strongly typed objects.

```
Private Function GetPlantSettingsFiltered(parameters As Dictionary(Of String, Object), queryCondition As String) As PlantSettings

    Dim query As String
    query = " SELECT * FROM Plant_Settings " _
          + queryCondition

    Dim settings As New PlantSettings
    Dim table As DataTable = GetQueryResults(parameters, query, GetConnectionString("WeighScaleDB"))

    If table Is Nothing Then
        Return settings
    End If

    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows

        settings.Add(New PlantSetting With {
                     .Setting_ID = ConvertByteArrayToString(TryCast(row("Setting_ID"), Byte())),
                     .Plant_ID = ConvertByteArrayToString(TryCast(row("Plant_ID"), Byte())),
                     .Value = row("Setting_Value").ToString(),
                     .Comments = row("Setting_Comments").ToString()
                 })

    Next

    Return settings

End Function
```

I would like to create a generic version of this function that would work for any of my objects without me creating this function for each object.

For example, if the caller could specify the type, then some other details, the function would return a collection of that type.

```
Private Function GetObjects(Of T)(parameters As Dictionary(Of String, Object), query As String) As WSAEntityCollection(Of T)

    Dim objectCollection As New WSAEntityCollection(Of T)

    Dim table As DataTable = GetQueryResults(parameters, query, GetConnectionString("WeighScaleDB"))

    If table Is Nothing Then
        Return objectCollection
    End If

    For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows

        ' Here is my problem
        objectCollection.Add(New T With {})

    Next

    Return objectCollection

End Function
```

My current problem with this new function is that I do not know how to dynamically match the column names with the parameters of the generic object. Any ideas on how this could be done?

Comment: This is the basic stuff at the base of every Object Relational Mapper. Probably the best choice is to use one instead.

Comment: Another way might be to use index. Or if this is a DLL you could have them pass you the specific column names.

Comment: Check out Reflection. You can use it to get/set the public properties of any object.

Comment: Without using an ORM or Reflection, the best approach should be to pass a generic function to the method. This function will be called inside the loop and will receive the current DataRow. Usually this function is located inside the class that need to retrieve its data and knows how to map its properties to the DataRow fields. However this code has serious problems. You are, at all effects, looping two times over your data and this, if coupled with a lot of rows could be disastrous for the performances